# Vuejs alternative method to target/currentTarget in list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My current setup is like below:

```
[{
     name: "test", 
     tags: ["aa","bb","v"]
 }, 
...]

<div class="item" v-for="item in sdList" :data-id="item.id">
      <span @click="deleteTag(item, $event)" v-for="tag in item.tags">{{tag}}</span>
</div>

methods: {
  deleteTag(item,event){
      event.target.style.display = "none";
  }   
}
```

Problem is `event.target` or `event.currentTarget` wont work properly. `currentTarget` does not point to the element after the bubbling finishes and `target` points to wrong object sometimes.

How can i implment `v-show` directive here, or any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually need to remove item from the list you can change the code to

```
  [{
     name: "test", 
     tags: ["aa","bb","v"]
    }, ...]

<div class="item" v-for="item,index in sdList" :data-id="item.id">
  <span @click="deleteTag(index)" v-for="tag in item.tags">
    {{tag}}
  </span>
</div>

methods: {
 deleteTag(itemIndex){
    this.sdList.splice(itemIndex, 1);
 }   
}
```